# Remove bundle but keep its msi as installed

Tags: .net, wix, windows-installer, wixsharp

I want to create an installer like a Resharper or VisualStudio with few msi inside the bundle and with three buttons for each msi:

- install/update
- skip
- remove

i'm using own UI and own BootstrapperApplication.
i have two same bundles but different versions

- bundle version 1 (v1)

  - mysql v1
  - notepad++ v1
- bundle version 2 (v2)

  - mysql v2
  - notepad++ v2

1) i installed bundle version 1 - it is ok, now i have bundle, mysql, notepad++ are installed
2) then i run bundle version 2 and want to update only mysql and skip update notepad++ and here is the problem:

bundle v2 doing following:

- update mysql to v2 - it's ok
- calls bundle v1 with flags -uninstall -quiet and this bundle v1 removes notepad++ - it's not ok

questions:

- is it possible to remove bundle and keep its msi as installed?

Comment: By design, bundles and MSIs have a many-to-many relationship. It is also anticipated that some MSIs won't have been installed only by bundles, making reference counting inaccurate. So, consider if [`MsiPackage/@Permanent`](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/msipackage.html) applies to you scenario.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes i marked msi's as Permanent and uninstall it manually in my BootstrapperApplication